# faster replacement of -1 and 0 to NaNs in column for a large dataset

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

The 'azdias' is a dataframe which is my main dataset and meta data or feature summary of it lies in dataframe 'feat_info'. The 'feat_info' shows the values in every column that have been displayed as NaN.

Ex: column1 has values [-1,0] as NaN values. So my job will be to find and replace these -1,0 in column1 as NaN.

azdias dataframe:
[image]

feat_info dataframe:
[image]
I have tried following in jupyter notebook.

```
def NAFunc(x, miss_unknown_list):
    x_output = x
    for i in miss_unknown_list:
        try:
            miss_unknown_value = float(i)
        except ValueError:
            miss_unknown_value = i
        if x == miss_unknown_value:
            x_output = np.nan
            break
    return x_output

for cols in azdias.columns.tolist():
    NAList = feat_info[feat_info.attribute == cols]['missing_or_unknown'].values[0]
    azdias[cols] = azdias[cols].apply(lambda x: NAFunc(x, NAList))
```

Question 1: I am trying to impute NaN values. But my code is very
   slow. I wish to speed up my process of execution.

I have attached sample of both dataframes:

azdias_sample

```
  AGER_TYP ALTERSKATEGORIE_GROB ANREDE_KZ CJT_GESAMTTYP FINANZ_MINIMALIST
0   -1          2                    1         2.0             3
1   -1          1                    2         5.0             1
2   -1          3                    2         3.0             1
3    2          4                    2         2.0             4
4   -1          3                    1         5.0             4
```

feat_info_sample

```
attribute            information_level       type          missing_or_unknown           
AGER_TYP                     person       categorical            [-1,0]
ALTERSKATEGORIE_GROB         person       ordinal                [-1,0,9]
ANREDE_KZ                    person       categorical            [-1,0]
CJT_GESAMTTYP                person       categorical            [0]
FINANZ_MINIMALIST            person       ordinal                [-1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `azdias` dataset is obtained from `read_csv` or similar IO functions, the `na_values` keyword argument can be used to specify column-specific missing value representations to make sure the returned data frame already has in-place NaN values from the very beginning. The sample code is shown in the following.

```
from ast import literal_eval

feat_info.set_index("attribute", inplace=True) 
# A more concise but less efficient alternative is
# na_dict = feat_info["missing_or_unknown"].apply(literal_eval).to_dict()
na_dict = {attr: literal_eval(val) for attr, val in feat_info["missing_or_unknown"].items()}
df_azdias = pd.read_csv("azidas.csv", na_values=na_dict)
```

As for the data type, there is no built-in NaN representation for integer data types. Hence a float data type is needed. If the missing values are imputed using `fillna`, the `downcast` argument can be specified to make the returned series or data frame have an appropriate data type.

Comment: I am new to coding and python. Here the feat_info has values in string format. So i guess i would need to convert them first. Hence can I do it directly while using read_csv?

Comment: I've provided sample code that should work as long as there are no duplicate attribute names.

Comment: By the way, the `index_col` argument can be used while calling `read_csv` to make the data frame have an appropriate index (e.g. the `attribute` column) at the very beginning. `read_csv` also provides many other powerful preprocessing functionalities that one should make good use of.

Comment: I tried your code, but it does not replace the values with NaN. Maybe because the missing_or_unknown column of feat_info is of string data type?

Comment: Yeah, the strings need to be converted to lists first. I've tried to update the code. I cannot test the correctness if no copy-pastable input and output data are provided for testing.

Comment: Is it possible that I share you a sample privately?

Comment: You can copy the output data frames (as text) from Jupyter Notebook and paste it in your question to replace the screenshots. In this way other people can also help.

Comment: Is the update still not working? Are there any error messages or is it just the result that is undesired?

Comment: Bro !! I have uploaded text sample to help you frame a code. Please let me know if this would help you to help me. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Since my solution involves data loading it would be better that you can also provide a few lines of the original data files. I can try to have a look later tonight if I have time.

Comment: Yes ! I have given sample in above question. image as well as typed in text format. Please confirm if that is what you wish. :) Take care bro.

Comment: What I mean is some text from the original files that the data are loaded from (so I can test `pd.read_csv`), not only the text generated from the loaded dataframes as you've already shown. I forgot to mention about that yesterday.

Comment: I think my code would work on the sample data you provided (if your input data is a well-formed csv file). There has to be other problems in your data that cause the failure.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the DataFrame's [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) method. How about this?

```py
for c in azdias.columns.tolist():
    replace_list = feat_info[feat_info['attribute'] == c]['missing_or_unknown'].values
    azidias[c] = azidias[c].replace(to_replace=list(replace_list), value=np.nan)
```

A couple things I'm not sure about without being able to execute your code:

1. In your example, you used `.values[0]`. Don't you want all the values?
2. I'm not sure if it's necessary to do `to_replace=list(replace_list)`, it may work to just use `to_replace=replace_list`.

In general, I recommend thinking to yourself "surely Pandas has a function to do this for me." Often, they do. For performance with Pandas generally, avoid looping over and setting things. Vectorized methods tend to be much faster.

Comment: Hi @blthayer. Thanks for replying. I am extracting only the values of particular column from feat_info that represents NaN. Hence I take value[0]. Ex: for AGER_TYP it will fetch list [-1,0]

Comment: also the values of missing_or_unknown are in string format that would need to be converted first to match data type of column. Hence using to_replace throwing me an error.

Comment: @KaustubhUrsekar - as to your first comment: understood. As to your second comment: try using [`astype`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) on your `missing_or_unknown` arrays to cast them to the correct type before calling the replacement. Note that `atype` is a method of `numpy.ndarray`, so in my code above you would need to do this **before** calling `list(replace_list)`

Comment: hi brother !! I have attached text file as sample to help you try at your side ! :)

Comment: Bro I need them in float but problem is that as I scan the dataframe of feat_info. I see 'Xx' too as representing NaNs. Hence I cant convert them to one single data type. Therefore I wrote the function of try and except in my code by reading documentation. But I am badly stuck on the time that function consumes to execute the conversion and impute NaNs. total rows are 890000 approx.